# asm.js vs plain javascript and closure performance

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, closures, asm.js

While doing some tests on asm.js (trying to write asm by hand), I had some weird benchmarks results on jsperf with Firefox.

I tried to follow [this](http://jsperf.com/asm-js-for-loop/2) tutorial containing a simple loop over an ArrayBuffer.

When tested on Google Chrome 39, the result was perfect, but on Firefox 31, I encountered the following two issues:

1. There is no performance gain when using asm.js (even if I get
   "Successfully compiled asm.js code");
2. using a native for loop is 20x faster inside a closure.

I guess there is something wrong with my code (as I'm new to JavaScript and closure in particular).

Any help?

Comment: You see a jsperf artifact. jsperf prevents compilation of the code in the tests, you should always define functions in the init part.

Comment: I moved my functions in the "preparation code" and it solved issue #2. But the first issue remains open: still no difference with or without the "use asm" pragma.

Comment: I see there's still no answer. asm.js isn't widely used, maybe you should contact the asm.js team ?